# How to parse JSON and determine if values are collections or nested collections?

Tags: python, json

I am looking for different ways to check values within JSON.

For instance, to check that the value is:

- int - `isinstance(value, int)`
- String - `isinstance(value, str)`
- Array - `isinstance(value, list)`

But what is the cleanest way to check if values are `list`, `dict` or a list of dictionaries? How to correctly differentiate between them?

#### Example

```
{
  "test": ["a","b"]
}
```

vs

```
{
  "test": {"a":0, "b":1}
}
```

vs

```
{
  "test": [
    {"a":0},
    {"b":1}
  ]
}
```

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert not 100% sure how this related to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recursively search through a JSON data structure, and handle the case where the items are collections such as lists or dictionaries, you could do something like the following.

#### Example: Recursively search for JSON key

```
def find_key(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for k, v in json_input.items():
            if k == lookup_key:
                yield v
            else:
                yield from find_key(v, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from find_key(item, lookup_key)
```

Also, be sure to take advantage of the standard library [**json**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) package.  The main functions for JSON encoding and decoding are:

- [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)
- [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

#### See also

- [recursive iteration through nested json for specific key in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21028979/1164465)
- [Iterating through a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2733813/1164465)
- [Validate JSON data using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491156/validate-json-data-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

If JSON data schema validation is what you are after, the examples you gave can be easily handled by [GoodJSON](https://github.com/namoshizun/goodjson)

**Is list (of specific type of values)**

```python
from goodjson.validators import gj_all, foreach, is_list, is_string

validate_fn = gj_all(
    is_list(),
    foreach(is_string)
)
validate_fn(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

**Is dict**

```python
from goodjson.validators import foreach_key, is_dict

validate_fn = foreach_key(test=[is_dict])
validate_fn({
    'test': {
        'is_dict': 'yes'
    }
})
```

**Is list of dict**

```python
from goodjson.validators import foreach_key, foreach, is_dict, is_list

validate_fn = foreach_key(
    test=[
        is_list(),
        foreach(is_dict)
    ]
)
validate_fn({
    'test': [{'foo': 'bar'}]
})
```