# Python JSON get value by string path

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, path, nested

I have a JSON file that I want to automatically check specific values,
like: `myJSON['generic']['lessgeneric']['store']` should be equal to `100`,

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
checks = [
    {'name':'field_1','path':'myJSON['generic']['lessgeneric']['store']','value':'100'}
]
```

I have no clue how to convert the string `"myJSON['generic']['lessgeneric']['store']"` into it's value.

edit:
how I solved it

```
path = "generic>lessgeneric>store"
value = 100
def check_value(path,value):
    temp_json = my_json
    for key in path.split(">"):
        temp_json = temp_json[key]
    if temp_json == value:
        pass
```

Comment: If you have control over things, a list of keys would be much safer to use. If what you ultimatley want to do is validate your json then I would look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491156/validate-json-data-using-python

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the path like that, I suggest you store it as a list or as a delimited string. For example:

```
checks = [ {'name': 'field_1', 'path': 'generic/lessgeneric/store', 'value': 100} ]
```

Then, you can split the value of the `path` key with `str.split()`, and drill down into your object. The following recursive function takes an object (that we expect to be a dictionary) and a list containing all the keys to drill down into, and returns the value at the final key:

```
def drill_down(obj, path):
    if len(path) == 1: 
        # if path has a single element, return that key of the dict
        return obj[path[0]] 
    else:
       # Take the key given by the first element of path. Then drill down into it
       return drill_down(obj[path[0]], path[1:])
```

Then, do:

```
for c in checks:
    path = c['path'].split('/')
    assert drill_down(myJSON, path) == c['value']
```

This assumes you've already parsed your json into an object in the `myJSON` variable using the `json` module.